# Persistent "New provisioning message" notification from "CP Client"

Tags: notifications, 7.0-nougat, nokia-2

I recently bought a new Nokia 2, Android 7 Nougat smartphone, and ever since I have started using it, I keep getting weird notifications from 'CP Client' saying 'New provisioning message'.

When I tap it, nothing happens and I can't do anything about it. I slide it to the right to get it out of my notifications, but it just comes back after a few minutes, and I keep getting these messages every now and then, usually 4 at a time.

This is really annoying and I'm worried if this might be a virus. What should I do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) and see which app is responsible for that notification. I'm guessing it is your carrier related. Once you determine which app it is, uninstall it if it is an user app. And revert with your findings here

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Settings -> App info. This will show you all apps.
2. Click on Settings button (I) and you will find "show system". On clicking on it, all system apps will populate.
3. Now, find "cp client" and force quit, clear data, and clear cache.

Comment: I did the above however this did not solve my issue, then I restart my phone and went to cp client as explained in the comment above, then storage => then click on clear storage and clear cache, this resolved my issue, hope it will help you too.

Comment: this is equivalent to force quit. However in new version of android the option might change.